# Scaling Pytorch training on a single-machine with multiple CPUs (no GPUs)

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, ray, distributed-training, dataparallel

What is the best way to accelerate PyTorch training on a **single machine with multiple CPUs** (*NO GPUs*)?

- We need to speed up training for a customer, because the training dataset grew substantially recently
- We **can't use GPUs**, but we **can increase CPU-cores** and memory on a dedicated machine

I researched the usual options for accelerating PyTorch, but I can't figure out what the ***"right" approach*** is for a single-machine multiple-CPUs scenario:

**1 PyTorch `DataParallel` and `DistributedDataParallel`**

From reading the documentation, I got the impression that PyTorch's `DataParallel` and `DistributedDataParallel` are designed to work only with GPUs.

Is that assumption correct?
If not, could you point me to a code sample for correctly setting those up for CPUs?

**2 Vanilla PyTorch on CPUs**

We tested our vanilla PyTorch training loop on a single 8-core CPU machine.
All cores were used during training, which implies

- that PyTorch is somehow parallelizing across CPUs already
- and that we could add cores to speed things up.

But what is happening under the hood exactly?
We are assumingly not using data parallelization (or model parallelization for that matter), because we are using our unaltered training code.

Is naively adding cores and memory in that setup the right approach?

**3 Ray Train**

We set up Ray Train (based on [this](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/train/dl_guide.html)) and it worked fine on a single machine with multiple CPUs. It even has an explicit `use_gpu` flag to disable GPU usage.

However according to the documentation, Ray Train uses `DistributedDataParallel` under the hood. Referring to the questions raised in points 1) and 2) above, is Ray Train the recommended way to scale on a single CPU-only machine?

**4 did we miss anything?**

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on how pytorch was built, if you are using official binaries then it should already be using all avaliable cores, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: thanks, @AhmedAEK! So with official binaries you mean the ones referenced here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Comment: Furthermore, is any kind of data-parallelization going on under the hood? How is the workload distributed across the CPU cores?

Comment: It's distrubuted per operation basis, for example each thread convolves a different part of the image or sums a different part of the array or multiplies a different part of the matrix, the fundamental operations themselves are parallelized.